# Do reverse clauses with 'be/have/do' require 'that'?

Tags: grammar

I am looking at these sentences:

1. *The fool ***he is*** said this.*
2. *The job ***he has*** is hard.*
3. *The job ***he does*** is hard.*
4. *The suit ***he wears*** is black.*

The reverse clause #1 seems completely wrong to me. #2 and #3 look somewhat questionable, and #4 looks completely correct to me. However, adding ***that*** (The fool ***that he is*** said this.) seems to make it *more correct* in each case.

It seems like I would always prefer to use ***that*** for all ***be/have/do***-based reverse clauses to make them right.

My questions are: Is there a rule that makes #1, #2, #3 wrong? Or, perhaps, they are all correct?

On a side note, I have never come across a book that would comprehensively describe and explain English grammar on a formal level. Books tend to go by example, and kind-of coach people to do it right only on an intuitive level.

Answer (score 1):

All four sentences are fine.
The 'he' phrases are all "restrictive appositives", meaning (appositive =) phrases placed after a noun (restrictive =) that are essential to defining the identity of that noun.
For restrictive appositives, do not use a comma, but if nonrestrictive, use commas before and after the appositive phrase.